# how to filter - with rest Api by name column?

Tags: 2013, rest, ajax

I have used this query:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists(guid'"+guidList+"/items?$select=ID,Title,carNumberIfActive,fullName/Id&$expand=fullName/Id?$filter=fullName/Id eq ‘name'")
```

And get error for this (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException)

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

`_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/_api/web/lists(guid'"+guidList+"')/items?$select=Id,Title,carNumberIfActive,fullName/Id&$expand=fullName/Id?$filter=fullName/Id eq "+Id+""`

you should filter with "Id" if it is people picker field